# async call in useEffect is not resolving until the component unmounts

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

**tldr:** the await call inside a useEffect hook doesn't resolve itself until after the component starts to unmount, it just hangs until that happens. Not sure why this is happening or how to debug it. This is in a react-native expo project. Swapping the functional component out with a class based one works as expected.

---

given the following useEffect calls in an expo project

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('mount');
  return () => {
    console.log('unmount');
  };
}, []);


useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
        console.log('fetching')
        const stuff = await fetchStuff();
        console.log('fetched');
    };

    fetch();
}, [depA, depB]);
```

What I'm seeing in the console when the component is mounted is

'mount'

'fetching'

then when the component is unmounted I see

'unmount'

'fetched'

For some reason, the await call doesn't resolve until the component is unmounted. I've used this pattern in other parts of my code seemingly without issue so I can't figure out why this is happening here. When I swap the functional component out with a class it's working as expected. Any ideas on why this is happening? It looks like the fetchStuff call is being deferred until the component is about to unmount. Swapping fetchStuff out with `await new Promise((res) => res(null));` doesn't seem to make any difference

Full component looks something like

```
function WhatIsHappening({depA, depB}) {
    const [stuff, setStuff] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('mount');
      return () => {
        console.log('unmount');
      };
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
      const fetch = async () => {
        console.log('fetching')
        const stuff = await fetchStuff(depA, depB);
        console.log('fetched');

        setStuff(stuff)
      };

      fetch();
    }, [depA, depB]);

    return (
        <View>
            <ListStuff stuff={stuff}></ListStuff>
        <View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `fetchStuff` is broken - if it responded properly, say, if it were replaced with `await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000))` you'd see `fetched` after a second of being mounted

Comment: @CertainPerformance I replaced the fetchStuff call with `await new Promise((res) => res(null));` and I still seeing the same behavior

Comment: That sounds quite odd, maybe `console.log` has been patched and broken somehow? Can you make a live snippet in the question that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: Yeah it's quite odd. This is only happening in this one functional component. I can't post a snippet because I can't reproduce it outside of my app, definitely feels like like some environmental issue here. It's not a console.log problem, I looked at my server logs and the fetchStuff call doesn't happen until after the component unmounts.

Comment: Maybe, posting the complete component helps

Comment: @HaseebAnwar it's pretty basic component, I updated my post to show it

Comment: I see no overt issues with the code and can't reproduce the logs in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-call-in-useeffect-is-not-resolving-until-the-component-unmounts-wyeqgv). I think whatever the is causing the issue, it's not in this code.

Comment: Can you show me the code of `fetchStaff()` ? I think there is something wrong

Comment: Also check [depA, depB] if it's changing and re-rendering the whole thing again.

Comment: @wingsico I replaced fetchStuff with `await new Promise((res) => res(null));` and the results are the same, for some reason the await call doesn't resolve until the component starts to unmount itself

Comment: @FrederikoCesar all the console.log stuff only appears once

Answer (score -2):

There is something wrong with `fetchStuff`. This is a working version.

```js
async function fetchStuff() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => resolve("fetched"));
}
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/youthful-bassi-d48ex1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)